# How can I place div and iframe in the center?

Tags: html, css, iframe, slideshow

I wanted to position this slideshow in the center, but unfortunately, it won't work. I'm using inline CSS for this.

I have tried adding `display:inline-block;` and `width:100%;text-align:center;`, it still won't work. I also tried `text-align:center;`

This is the code I'm working on. I'm dumb when it comes to this and I'm having a hard time on my website, can't submit my project unless done.

```
<div class="cincopa_responsive_iframe" style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;">
<div class="cincopa_responsive_wrapper" style="height:100%;left:0;position:absolute;top:0;width:100%;">
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="//www.cincopa.com/media-platform/iframe.aspx?fid=AMNAChemJPN0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen scrolling="no">
</iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

What happens is that the slideshow appears on the upper left. I'm hoping for it to be at the center. Here is an image of how it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DU7X.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Inside iframes there is another html code which cant be manipulated with Css,may be with js ..When you inspect with DevTools in iframes/#documents/body there is #_wp_cincopa_1 which if set "margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto;"  can see changes..